# Save msg file as htm

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to save a list of email in msg format to htm format so that Xceptor tool can read the email as pdf. (<strike>Without a vba,</strike> Currently I manually open the email in Outlook and save as htm one by one.)

I found below script but I get

> "Run Time error 287: Application-defined or object-defined error".

```vb
Sub SaveMSG_as_HTML()

    Dim olMsg As MailItem
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strHTML As String
        
    strPath = "\\Hbap.adroot.hsbc\hk\Finance\224017\AMH_A2R_2\WRK\AAC\PL\To GFC\Movement Table\MvtXceptor\Configuration\Table18.1\"
    strMsg = "RE  CRR Inquiry as atJan-00-00 - --.msg"
    strHTML = Left(strMsg, InStrRev(strMsg, Chr(46))) & "html"
    Set olMsg = Session.OpenSharedItem(strPath & strMsg)
    olMsg.SaveAs Path:=strPath & strHTML, Type:=olHTML
    olMsg.Close olDiscard
lbl_Exit:
    Set olMsg = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Run-time error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error" while using CurrentItem.Saveas or CurrentItem.HTMLBody in Outlook 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204574/run-time-error-287-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-while-using)

Answer (score 1):

> Without a vba, i need to open the email in outlook and save as htm one by one.

Without VBA? So I guess you want to use `VBScript`? Say, directly run it from desktop by clicking on the `.vbs` file? If yes, then you need to declare and create/get the outlook object before you can work with it. Otherwise how will your code know what is `Session`? Also `olHTML` and `olDiscard` are Outlook constants. VbScript will not know what they are.

Is this what you are trying? Paste this in Notepad and save it as `Sample.Vbs`

```
Private Const olHTML = 5
Private Const olDiscard = 1

Dim OutApp
Dim olMsg
Dim nsOutlook

Dim strPath
Dim strMsg
Dim strHTML
  
'~~> I used these values for testing. Change as applicable
strPath = "C:\Temp\"
strMsg = "test.msg"
strHTML = "test.html"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set nsOutlook = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olMsg = nsOutlook.OpenSharedItem(strPath & strMsg)

olMsg.SaveAs strPath & strHTML, olHTML
olMsg.Close olDiscard

Set olMsg = Nothing
Set nsOutlook = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance.  My original script I put it in Excel visual basic.  But I have followed your instruction to use the suggested script in notepad and save in desktop as .vbs file.  When I run in desktop, i have below error:-  Script:  C:\Users\43918084\Desktop\emailmacro.vbs      Line:22    Char:   1     Error: Operation aborted         Code:80004004     Source : (null)

Comment: The above code is tried and tested. It works just fine for me. Line 22 is `olMsg.Close olDiscard` Did you change anything in the code? BTW did it create the html inspite of the error because the line previous to that creates the html.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your help.  I copied exactly the same code and even put the email in C:\Temp\ and change the email anme as test.msg.  Unfortunately, the email was not converted to htm.  I wonder if it relate to any security setting in Outlook by the company?

Comment: Could be the security settings. What happens if you remove the line `olMsg.Close olDiscard`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience to my problem.  I just note that my line 22 is olMsg.SaveAs strPath & strHTML, olHTML.  Just wondering if there is any work around if it is due to security setting?

Comment: What is the value of `strPath` & `strHTML`